Difference between Debug and Release mode in Dotnet Application in a specific scenario
I was going through to reading asynchronous programming in .NET
There mention about debug and release mode of simple program using thread.
Consider following code:
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         AsyncTest objAsyncTest = new AsyncTest();
   
         while(!objAsyncTest.isTerminate);
    }
}
 

public class AsyncTest
{
    public bool isTerminate { get; set; }
    
    public AsyncTest()
    {
        Thread monitorThread = new Thread(MoniterThread);
        monitorThread.Start();
    }
    
    public void MoniterThread()
    {
         Thread.Sleep(3000);
         isTerminate = true;
    }
}

So if I run above program in Debug mode, it will come out and stop in three second.
but if I run same program in Release mode. it never comes out and doesn't stop.
if someone could explain me whey it is so, would be very helpful.

The relevant difference is that in Release build optimizations are enabled.
One such valid optimization is for the main thread to assume that in this line:
while(!objAsyncTest.isTerminate);

isTerminate is actually never changed (because there is no such visible change in the current thread), and so the loop becomes an infinite one because isTerminate will be actually checked [potentially] only once.
One solution is to use a volatile field:

The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by
multiple threads that are executing at the same time. The compiler,
the runtime system, and even hardware may rearrange reads and writes
to memory locations for performance reasons. Fields that are declared
volatile are excluded from certain kinds of optimizations.

(emphasis is mine)
In your case:
//------vvvvvvvv--------------------------
private volatile bool isTerminate_ = false;

public bool isTerminate 
{ 
     get { return isTerminate_; } 
     set { isTerminate_ = value; } 
}

Making it volatile means the compiler must take into account that the field might be modified by another thread, and actually check it's value in each iteration - as you expect and as the Debug build behaves.
Another option is to use some blocking (synchronization) mechanism.
In addition to ensuring mutual exclusion, it also disables the optimization above. As menioned in the comment is even ensures the latest value of isTerminate_ is read regardless of cache issues.
Note: in your case it is quite an overkill, but you can see an example below.
One such synchronization mechanism is the lock statement.
In your case:
private bool   isTerminate_     = false;
private object isTerminate_lock = new object();  // to be used with the `lock` statement

public bool isTerminate
{
//--------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv---------------------------
    get { lock (isTerminate_lock) { return isTerminate_; } }
    set { lock (isTerminate_lock) { isTerminate_ = value; } }
}

Similar effect can be obtained by using other synchronization primitives like mutex.
But as mentioned above in your case it is an overkill and using volatile is enough.
A final note:
Having a tight loop for checking if a field has modified
(like while(!objAsyncTest.isTerminate);) is not a good practice, as it makes the main thread consume a lot of CPU time with no real reason.
You can consider to implement some signaling mechanism e.g. with AutoResetEvent.
But at the minimum you should add some Sleep between checks, e.g.:
while (!objAsyncTest.isTerminate)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
};


@Charlieface, both statements are wrong, volatile prohibits so called reordering-optimizations (you are allowed to read earlier, but not to read later), but there is no guarantee that most recent value is being read, check the source.

@Ryan thanks for the link. As I understand it in this case volatile will solve the OP's problem because if "The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by multiple threads" (from the documentation) then I believe the value must be read in each iteration (and therefore eventually be up-to-date) . Am I wrong ?

@wohlstad, you are right. OPs code sample is exactly the same as in documentation (as far as i remember), in that case it disables compiler optimization making the flow to read the value at every iteration. So, more complete definition of volatile is - it marks the field to be excluded from any kind of optimizations (compiler or reordering optimizations), but do not affect any cache-related mechanics (L1/L2 cache in multicore  environment, every core has its own L1/L2 storage => that's the problem). According to my experience.

So, despite of volatile is lock-free technique, that's worth of it, but it still does not provide guarantee for reading most recent value in memory in extremely high concurrent executions. Blocking techniques have benefits compared to this, imho.

@Ryan when you mention "Blocking techniques", you mean e.g. using the lock statement ?

@wohlstad, yep, or those vanilla mutex, semaphore types, etc.

@Ryan updated my answer and added a solution using lock.

@wohlstad, no, man, you made it worse. In current case just disable optimizations, that's all. I was regarding these concurrent tools in general. Every case should be considered individually.

@Ryan added some clarifications. Kept the blocking mechanism option just for general information and completeness.
